# Generic component

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.2

i need to define a set of generic component in Extjs4:
for example i want to define a single generic store and when i need a store in my code is necessary to create a store just define and pass to him the model and the url for get the data.
This is my store:

```
Ext.define('base.common.store.BaseStore',{
    extend:'Ext.data.Store',
    remoteSort: true,
    proxy: {
        //url:this.url,
        type: 'ajax',
        pageParam: false, //to remove param "page"
        startParam: false, //to remove param "start"
        limitParam: false, //to remove param "limit"
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            id: 'id',
            root: 'list'
        }
    }
})
```

and this is when i create an instance of it:

```
var dsGroups = Ext.create('base.common.store.BaseStore',{
            model:'base.common.model.Group'
            //proxy:{url:"Group.getGroups"}

        });
dsGroups.getProxy().url = "Group.getGroups";
```

This question is: There is a way to do this job for inject the proxy.url property in the Ext.create call? (i don't want to use the last statement)

Anytype of help or idea is usefull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Ext.define('base.common.store.BaseStore',{
    extend:'Ext.data.Store',
    remoteSort: true,

    defaultProxyCfg: {
        type: 'ajax',
        pageParam: false, //to remove param "page"
        startParam: false, //to remove param "start"
        limitParam: false, //to remove param "limit"
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            id: 'id',
            root: 'list'
        }
    }

    constructor: function(config){
        config = Ext.apply({}, config);
        config.proxy = Ext.apply({
            url: config.url
        }, this.defaultProxyCfg);
        this.callParent([config]);
    }
});
```